# merging 2 array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have 2 arrays. For example

```
x= [1,2,3,4,5]
y= [a,b,c,d,e]
```

How do I merge them so that I have an array like below

```
z=[[1,a],[2,b],[3,c],[4,d],[5,e]]
```

Comment: Does `x.zip(y)` answer your needs?

Comment: Thanks guys. I remember there was a way to do it but I just can't remember.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is.....

```
x.zip y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.9.3p194 :011 >   x= [1,2,3,4,5]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
1.9.3p194 :012 > y= ['a','b','c','d','e']
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] 
1.9.3p194 :013 > x.zip(y)
 => [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"], [5, "e"]]
```